# Bottom part of div Wavy shape without fixing height of div

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to make the bottom part of this div this shape[image]

```css
.shape {
  height: 200px;
  background: #e7ecf5;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">

</div>
```

I don't want to fix a height of this div.

Answer (score 1):

Edited: run the snippet

```css
.shape {
  height: 200px;
  background: #e7ecf5;
  position: relative;
  width: 1080px;
}

.svg {
  margin-top: -60px;
}

.svgpath {
  fill: #e7ecf5
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">

</div>
<svg class="svg" height="400" width="1080">
<path class="svgpath" d="M 0 100 Q 80 120 160 100 Q 250 90 330 100 Q 440 130 540 130 Q 640 130 750 100 Q 830 90 920 100 Q 1000 120 1080 100 Q 1080 75 1080 60 Q 540 60 0 60 Q 0 70 0 100 Z" />
</svg>
```

https://codepen.io/anthonydugois/pen/mewdyZ

This link may help you design it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only way to do this kind of "shape" in css using only one div element is to add a repeatable background with that image (can use svg provided above as a source).

More likely you'll need to add proper bottom padding and `box-sizing` to maintain the height.

Another approach is to use underlying absolutely positioned element being an svg image or canvas for example.